# Permitir Selecionar apenas PDF em JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, pdf

Gostaria de saber como faz para que ao escolher o arquivo para upload ele filtrar pela extensao .pdf nativo html ou por JS, Jquery.

Usando o type="file" ele traz todos os arquivos.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Selecione o arquivo PDF:</h1>

<h3>Selecione o PDF:</h3>
<form action="/action_page.php">
  <input type="file" name="myFile"><br><br>
  
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode utilizar dessa forma:

```html
<input type="file" accept="application/pdf">
```

[Aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Basico_sobre_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types) tem uma lista dos tipos de arquivos e os código `mime` que você pode usar, caso deseja utilizar mais de um, pode separar com `|`

Ex.:

```html
<input type="file" accept="application/pdf|image/*">
```

---

[Lista de compatibilidade da MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o Javascript válido pra qualquer navegador pra isso.

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Selecione o arquivo PDF:</h1>
    <h3>Selecione o PDF:</h3>
    <form action="/action_page.php">
        <input type="file" name="myFile"><br><br>
    </form>

<script>
    var file = document.getElementsByTagName('input').value();
    var tipo = file.split('.').pop();

    if(tipo != 'pdf'){
        alert('Arquivo não suportado');
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

De forma completa, temos a seguinte resposta para o seu caso:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <h1>Selecione o arquivo PDF:</h1>
    
    <h3>Selecione o PDF:</h3>
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <input type="file" accept="application/pdf">
      <br><br>
      
    </form>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```